# How to debug undefined method for helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

I have a rails application that is up and running on Ubuntu virtual machine and on several different installations.

I have a new computer and after installing Ruby and Rails (using rvm) I can run the application but when accessing views the helper functions are not found.  The `helper :all` line is in the `ApplicationController`.

I am pretty sure this is a problem with my environment and not the app. Is there a missing gem that would cause this problem?

Can you recommend any steps that I could take to debug this issue?

```
MacBook-Air:cyberdojo mike$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.7.0]
MacBook-Air:cyberdojo mike$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.11
```

The actual error I get is this:

```
NoMethodError in Dojo#create

Showing app/views/dojo/create.html.erb where line #62 raised:

undefined method `ellided_name' for #<ActionView::Base:0x101fabf70>
Extracted source (around line #62):

59:        value="<%=@dojo.name-%>" />
60: 
61: <h1 title="<%= @dojo.name-%>">   
62:   <%= ellided_name(@dojo.name, 40) %>
63: </h1>
64: 
65: <table align="center">
```

The source code can be seen here:  https://github.com/meekrosoft/cyberdojo

Comment: Please show the precise, actual error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `vendor` directory has a bunch of symlinks to `/usr/share/rails`.  That's probably why it's working on some servers (because on those servers those symlinks are working) and not on others.

Your helpers aren't working because they should be within modules, so `app/helpers/ellided_name.rb` should have:

```
module EllidedName
  # code you have in the file now
end
```

I'm guessing that some older version of Rails (the one you have in `/usr/share/rails` on your servers) allowed the non-module syntax.

**Warning** based on the 2.1.0 in your `config/environments.rb` this app has been around for a long time, and if the `/usr/share/rails` version is anywhere close to 2.1 then this will be the first of many problems you'll have trying to run this app as-is in 2.3.

### Update

The OP discovered a gap in my recommendation, I'm just adding it here for anyone who finds this in google - he **also** needed to add the `_helper` suffix to the filenames, so as well as adding the `module` wrappers within the files he had to change `app/helpers/ellided_name.rb` to `app/helpers/ellided_name_helper.rb` and (he didn't say, but I'm sure) the module name needed to reflect this, so `EllidedNameHelper` instead of just `EllidedName`

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Is it ok to just update these symlinks to the rvm installation?

Comment: It's ok in that it won't make your computer explode, try it and see if your app works :)

Comment: I tried deleting the contents of the vendor directory and doing gem install rails -v=2.1.0.  When I run the app with script/server I can see that the 2.1.0 version is being run.  This had the same results as before.

Comment: Forgot to say, I have also added the helper in a module as you suggested.

Comment: I tried pasting the helper method directly into the `ApplicationController` and it still didn't find the method.  I think there is a fundamental issue with my rails install.  I will rm -rf ~/.rvm and re-install everything to see if I can fix it with a clean ruby and rails install.

Comment: Just checked, those links in the vendor directory are invalid on the server also so that doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: Pasting the method into `ApplicationController` - you will also need to add a call to [`helper_method`](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.1.0/doc/index.html?a=M000327&name=helper_method) to make the method available to the view.  Give that a try, and then I'm really out of ideas.  Might jst be a "too damn old" problem for this app on a new installation - so much has changed since 2.1, and if your Rails is requiring some newer gem, it's easy for something to get screwed up.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your help.  Your answer sent me along the correct path.  The helper files needed to be renamed to end in _helper.rb and the file contents surrounded by the module definition like you said. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, HA!  I didn't even notice that when looking at them.  Still weird that it was working in some of your environments, but well done!